# Multiple sizes of <select> element using Ryan Fait's jQuery styling script

Tags: jquery, css, select, input

I'm a complete novice at java and can do pretty much nil by myself. I'm wondering how to modify Ryan Fait's input styles jQuery so as to allow 2 different types of  elements. Here's the link to his very helpful code:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Basically it works very smoothly but I can't figure out how to do 2 different sizes (one big, one small, therefore with different background images also) of a  menu. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's typically not a good idea to mess with OS controls since some users may be used to them or depend on them to look a certain way they have set up, but it is very popular to do this, especially with submit buttons.

Comment: @tandu some users maybe used to them? its not good reasoning for not styling elements, are you used to stackoverflow design and only want to see all the websites that have a similar look!?

Comment: @user1394674 at least provide a markup! what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the sizes of the elements are hard-coded in the source, which is an unfortunate side-effect of the way the code has been written. While you could make a lot of  changes to the source code so that it accepts multiple styles, you'd be better off *just using CSS* and a bit of extra HTML.

If your HTML looked like this:

```
<label for="first">Specially styled select box</label>
<div class="styled-select">
    <select name="first">
        <option>Here is the first option</option>
        <option>The second option</option>
    </select>
</div>

<label for="first">Specially styled select box, with massive text</label>
<div class="styled-select">
    <select name="second" class="massive">
        <option>Here is the first option</option>
        <option>The second option</option>
    </select>
</div>
​
```

Your stylesheet might look something like this:

```
.styled-select {
    width: 240px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(http://cdn.bavotasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/down_arrow_select.jpg) no-repeat right #DDD;
}
.styled-select select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

select.massive {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

See it in action with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjmHy/8/).

(Source: [bavotsan.com](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/))